# Magento - Allow edit of only one CMS page for certain role

Tags: magento, content-management-system, user-roles

In my eshop I have a role for some users that is quite limited. I would like to give the ability to this role to be able to edit ONE and only that one CMS page. I don't want to allow them to edit all CMS pages. Is there any workarround?

Any other trick I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i think you can custom query in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Grip.php file check  protected function _prepareCollection() function.write query with check current logged admin user & page_id